# HighStock bubble chart navigator makes bubbles disappear

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a bubble chart on which I want to use the HighStock navigator component. The tricky part is that it seems that sometimes the entire chart just gets displayed as a blank section. No axis, nothing.

When you go to the page it draws well. Now grab the left handle and drag to the right. At some point, you will see that the chart just doesn't render anything even though there is definitely data there.

I reduced the case to the two sample. One works, one doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/scyog0hc/ - `just fine`

http://jsfiddle.net/aws9pp94/ - `eventually breaks`

I noticed that in the second one, it breaks because there is a repeated X value.
[image: Eventually breaks]

The third case is when the x values are "Close Enough". It breaks in a slightly different way. http://jsfiddle.net/4sb59o7b/

I think for a bubble chart it makes sense that there could be two bubbles on the same or "close enough" x values. Especially in a time based chart when I'm representing events, this makes perfect sense.

How can I get the navigator to work right?

Comment: It's a bug in Highstock, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2055). Workaround should be possible by setting `xAxis.ordinal` to false and adding extra two points (at the beginning and at the end of series.data) with null values.